# IF OR/& statement faster than two if statements?

Tags: vba, performance, loops, if-statement

I was wondering if there was a general rule regarding the sequence of several `IF` statements, taking `OR`statements and `&` combination into consideration.

e.g. below is my initial thought about the fastest way

```
Dim DataRCntr As Long
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim Target As String
Dim DataArr() As Variant
Dim StrArr() As Variant

DataArr = MyRange.Value

StrArr = Array(Target, "High", "Major", Target & "High", Target & "Major")

For DataRCntr = LBound(DataArr, 1) To UBound(DataArr, 1)

    If DataArr(DataRCntr, 4) & DataArr(DataRCntr, 11) = StrArr(2) Or _
    DataArr(DataRCntr, 4) & DataArr(DataRCntr, 11) = StrArr(3) Then

        If DataArr(DataRCntr, 20) < 0.9 Then

        'Do Something

        End If

    End If

Next DataRCntr
```

Example of a few things i was thinking about:

1. In first `IF` statement, you could split it up in two so you first check for `DataArr(DataRCntr, 4)=StrArr(1)` to avoid the `OR` statement if the first doesn't match
2. You could create a String combining `DataArr(DataRCntr, 4) & DataArr(DataRCntr, 11)`before the `IF` statement

Comment: Why didn't you perform a runtime test yourself? I believe this can also depend on how your data looks like. So there may be no general answer beside testing it on your own.

Comment: Okay, I was mostly curious about whether there was a general tendency/rule and not regarding a specific piece of code.

Comment: @Sebastian Koefoed, 1) `VBA` doesn't have a "short-circuit"ing, so your `OR` statement will evaluate anyway, hence your idea is reasonable, why not? 2) It's a **must**, but it's only a habit in general. About question: There're no rules, no one will blame you (except employers, coleagues and internet code crusaders) for your coding habits. While you sufficient with code - use it and try to learn something new. Repeat. (*So there may be no general answer* @Peh)